# ¿Cómo se puede ejecutar un Query SELECT con múltiples operaciones de las columnas?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Digamos que tengo una tabla llamada T, con las columnas C1 y C2.
Se puede escribir el Query:

```
SELECT C1,C2,C1+C2 As Suma FROM T
```

y va a regresar las columnas originales y la suma de ellas, pero quiero hacer múltiples operaciones con la suma de ambas columnas y poner la suma y su operación sería muy ineficiente en código y muy confuso. Se podría escribir:

```
SELECT C1,C2,C1+C2 As Suma, ABS(C1+C2) As 'Suma abs', EXP(C1+C2) As 'Suma elebada a la e potencia'  FROM T
```

(Esté es un ejemplo nada más) me gustaría hacer algo parecido a lo que se hace en programación estructurada declarando una "columna" con el valor de la suma de las columnas C1 y C2 y luego utilizarla varias veces algo como:

```
columna suma = C1+C2;
SELECT C1,C2,suma As Suma, ABS(suma) As 'Suma abs', EXP(suma) As 'Suma elebada a la e potencia'  FROM T
```

¿Existe alguna manera elegante de hacerlo en lugar de repetir la operación después de cada coma?
Nota: estoy utilizando MySQL versión 5.7.37

Doy gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan.

Comment: Si lo hacés dentro de algún procedimiento de base si podes usar variables sin dramas, pero de todas formas, no le veo el problema a hacer el calculo en esa sentencia.

Answer (score 3):

Podrías solucionarlo usando una variable:

```
select C1,C2, @suma:=(C1+C2), ABS(@suma), EXP(@suma)
FROM T
```

Comment: funciona bien en cPanel, pero cuando intento de ejecutarlo desde el dataset de visual studio, no funciona, pero ese ya es otro tipo de problema, muchas gracias, es lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que también podrías usar procesos almacenados para tener el valor guardado de la suma en cualquier momento.

```
DECLARE sumaColumna INT; 
SET sumaColumna:= PARAMETRO1+PARAMETRO2;
```

O como dices "declarar" la columna podrías crear una  nueva para aquellas dos columnas que quieres sumar y asignarle un valor a cada uno de sus registros, aunque esto lo veo no tan eficiente.

Comment: me aparece que "DECLARE" es un tipo de declaración desconocida (irónico), pero gracias de cualquier forma

Comment: @manuelduv Estas usando el BEGIN y END?